# How do I make a forward-proxy server on k8s and ALB(or NLB)?

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, tor, amazon-eks, privoxy

I created forward proxy server on EKS pods behind ALB(created by  `AWS Load Balancer Controller`). All pod can take a response through 8118 port through ALB.

The resources like pod and ingress looked good to me. Then I tried if the proxy server work well with `curl -Lx k8s-proxy-sample-domain.ap-uswest-1.elb.amazonaws.com:18118 ipinfo.io`

Normally, I get random ip address from **ipinfo.io**. But it didn't.... So, I also did `port-forad`. Like this:

```sh
kubectl port-forward specifi-pod 8118:8118
```

Then I re-try redirect access on my host address.

```sh
curl -Lx localhost:8118 ipinfo.io
```

In this case, it went well. I cannot catch the reason. What's the difference between `THROUGH ALB` and `port-forward`. Should I use NLB for some reason? Or some misconfigure?

### My environement

- k8s version: v1.18.2
- node type: fargate

### Manifest

Here is my manifest.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: tor-proxy
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: tor-proxy
  name: tor-proxy-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: tor-proxy
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: tor-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: dperson/torproxy
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: tor-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8118

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: tor-proxy
  name: tor-proxy-service
  namespace: tor-proxy
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 18118
      targetPort: 8118
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: tor-proxy
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: tor-proxy
  name: tor-proxy-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 18118}]'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: tor-proxy-service
              servicePort: 18118
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NLB` not `ALB`, because it pass the client IP toward a target site through proxy server.

Comment: could it be used in vsphere virtual machines without aws?